# What is the modern day equivalent of a "dandy?"

Tags: meaning

The Japanese still use this word to describe how a person dresses. However I'm sure that their idea of *dandy* is different from what I saw in Wikipedia, which shows pictures of men from hundreds of years ago.

I tried to ask [this question on the Japanese stackexchange board](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2176/what-is-a), but it didn't quite answer my question.

What is the modern-day English equivalent of a "dandy?"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know what your usage in Japanese is, but the meaning of dandy is simply "*someone who is particular about his dress and appearance*". It's not required that a dandy dress in 18th century costume.

so a modern-day word for dandy is

```
dandy
```

A more modern word would be ***metrosexual***

> a heterosexual man who spends a lot of time and money on his appearance and likes to shop

For some more underused and fancy words, there is the [thesaurus](http://www.synonyms.net/synonym/dandy) from which I find

dude, fop, gallant, sheik, beau, swell, fashion plate, clotheshorse

Comment: The word *dandy* certainly makes me think of 18th and 19th century fops.  I wouldn't call a modern man a dandy.  Metrosexual is spot on though.

Comment: @z7sg: My recent recollection of *dandy* was reading about Jude Law's character in Alfie referred to as one. [Jude Law modelled his performance in ALFIE on soccer star DAVID BECKHAM - whom he considers a "dandy"](http://www.contactmusic.com/news/jude_law/1-1) - so I assumed the word is still current in BrE.

Comment: He actually says "I think David Beckham is a perfect example of a dandy (of today)".  You are right that it can still be used but it does have an association, it is strongly nuanced and I find this makes it somewhat derogatory as opposed to *metrosexual*.

Answer (score 1):

***hipster*** , if you meant slavish dedication to countertrends

(*dandy* - 1. a man unduly devoted to style, neatness, and fashion in dress and appearance)

Also, ***metrosexual*** is ok.